# LocalAccounts only guide?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have tried following this guide for setting up custom policies: [Tutorial: Create user flows and custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

But with the LocalAccounts only sample files. When running the custom policies it fails with a very generic error message.

> Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.
> We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In the meantime, please try again.

What I would really love is either:

1. A guide for setting up LocalAccount custom policies with SendGrid integration or
2. A SendGrid integration for the UserFlows (kept simple, supply API key and template ids)

Comment: Hi, if any of the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable application insights logging to better understand what's going on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

About SendGrid, there is a tutorial for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy. You can't use SendGrid with USer Flows but only with Custom Policies.

Comment: Thanks. I know them both. I will try with AppInsigths to see if I can figure out what is going on. Also, I know that SendGrid is not available right now for userflows - my wish is that it becomes available one day. Would be really neat.

Comment: Thanks - it actually helped! :D The problem was "The supplied request must present a code_challenge" - so i could supply a static value to test it.

Answer (score 0):

In the pre-requisites of that doc, you can use my [IEF Setup Tool](https://aka.ms/iefsetup), which autoamtes the article. If you select the "Remove facebook" option, you will deploy the Local+Social+MFA starter pack with the LocalAccount journey. This keeps all dependancies available if you change your mind later on.

Then you can test the policy from the Azure Portal:

1. [Create an app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga) with https://jwt.ms as the reply url and implict flow enabled.
2. [Test the policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#test-the-custom-policy).

Custom email providers doesnt work for User Flows, you require Custom Policies.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Thanks. 
1. I have tested it and it failed :) created a github issue for you.
I know - but my wish is there was an integration with sendgrid.

Comment: Ah that sample needs updating based off some fresh changes in the normal starter pack. Remove everything between the `<Localization>` and `</Localization>` tags, including these two tags themselves from the `DisplayControl_TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml` file. Or follow the article fully to update your own policy. Our generic integration allows integration with **any** provider. Setup is a one time operation.

Comment: Thanks - any help setting up a custom email verification using sendgrid is much apprecciated. Can you make sure that the guide is up to date and that it actually works? It also assumes that there you already use custom policies. I think that many going migrating to custom policies exactly because of the e-custom e-mail templates and hence a basic migration guide with working examples from userflow to custom policies for signin/signup, reset password and edit profile would be very helpfull.

Comment: The answer is the end to end guidance. There is no direct migration from user flow to custom policy’s. Once you use my setup tool, follow my last link fully.